# Next Button force closes app unexpectedly?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

The program is a simple music player, but the next button force closes the app whenever it is pressed.

```
         public void next(View view) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next song", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mp.reset();
            if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)){
                mp.selectTrack(SONG_NUMBER + 1);
                SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER + 1;
            }
            else {
                mp.start();
                SONG_NUMBER = 0;
             }
            mp.start();
}
```

this is the rest of the code

```
package com.android.SimplePlayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.SimplePlayer.R;
import com.example.SimplePlayer.R.id;
import com.example.SimplePlayer.R.layout;
import com.example.SimplePlayer.R.string;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
}
}
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnCompletionListener {
private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private View play;
private View pause;
private View stop;
private View next;
public static int SONG_NUMBER=0;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlaylist();
    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    stop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    next.setEnabled(true);
  }

@Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    try { 
        SONG_NUMBER=position;
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        play.setEnabled(false);
        pause.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        next.setEnabled(true);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void updatePlaylist() {
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item,songs);
    setListAdapter(songList);
}
}
  public void play(View view){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing song", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       mp.start();
       play.setEnabled(false);
       pause.setEnabled(true);
       stop.setEnabled(true);
       next.setEnabled(true);
       }



  public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing song", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mp.pause();
      play.setEnabled(true);
      pause.setEnabled(false);
      stop.setEnabled(true);
      next.setEnabled(true);
   }    


  public void stop(View view){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopping song", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mp.stop();
          play.setEnabled(false);
          pause.setEnabled(false);
          stop.setEnabled(false);
  }


      public void next(View view) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next song", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mp.reset();
            if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)){
                mp.selectTrack(SONG_NUMBER + 1);
                SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER + 1;
            }
            else {
                mp.start();
                SONG_NUMBER = 0;
             }
            mp.start();
}

 @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
        try { 
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER + 1));
            if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)){
                SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER + 1;
            } 
            else {
                mp.start();
                SONG_NUMBER = 0;
             }
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            play.setEnabled(false);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            next.setEnabled(true);
        } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
 }
}
```

Anyone know of how to solve this problem? I would appreciate it a lot.

Here are my logcat errors

```
10-19 01:32:16.428: E/MediaPlayer(7511): start called in state 1
10-19 01:32:16.428: E/MediaPlayer(7511): error (-38, 0)
10-19 01:32:16.428: E/MediaPlayer(7511): start called in state 0
10-19 01:32:16.461: E/MediaPlayer(7511): Error (-38,0)
10-19 01:32:16.473: E/MediaPlayer(7511): start called in state 2
10-19 01:32:16.473: E/MediaPlayer(7511): error (-38, 0)
10-19 01:32:16.474: E/MediaPlayer(7511): prepareAsync called in state 0
10-19 01:32:16.491: D/AndroidRuntime(7511): Shutting down VM
10-19 01:32:16.491: W/dalvikvm(7511): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ff39a8)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.SimplePlayer.MainActivity.onCompletion(MainActivity.java:148)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2044)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
10-19 01:32:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `logcat` output would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout logic is wrong. `(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1))` will never be `true`.

So what happens is you call `mp.start()` twice, one in `else` clause, one right after it. That's why the exception says something about `start called in state...`

What you probably want to do is this:

```
if(SONG_NUMBER < songs.size()-1){
    SONG_NUMBER += 1;
    mp.selectTrack(SONG_NUMBER);
} else {
    SONG_NUMBER = 0;
}
mp.start();
```

Comment: would changing it to `(SONG_NUMBER > (SONG_NUMBER - 1))` and taking out the second `mp.start();` work>

Comment: @soul6942 Do you undersdand `(SONG_NUMBER > (SONG_NUMBER - 1))`? Look at it and think what it checks for. What is the point of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)){
    mp.selectTrack(SONG_NUMBER + 1);
    SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER + 1;
} else {
    mp.start();
    SONG_NUMBER = 0;
}
```

Hey in on next click,  it always goes in else part because that condition never satisfy. and you have added mp.reset() and later on you are trying to mp.start() You have to add data source to mp before starting that music.

Comment: i tried `if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)) { mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER + 1));` but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void prev(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Previous song", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      try {
        if(SONG_NUMBER < songs.size()+1){
            SONG_NUMBER -= 1;
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
        }
        else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot play previous song", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        prev.setEnabled(false);
        }
        mp.start();
         } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
         }
  }
```

based on the next button, I tried making a previous button. It works unless you are playing the first song, then it force closes. I want it so that if you press the previous button, the `prev.setEnabled()` changes to false and the music keeps playing. Also I want it so that it says that it cannot play previous song when they try.

Comment: can you think of what i can change? @Oleksiy